# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of P(x|theta) = 1/(1-theta)

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I want to calculate the maximum likelihood estimation of $P(x|\theta) = 1/(1-\theta)$ for $\theta<= x <=1$.

I end up with $log1 - nlog(1-\theta)$ and when I want to take the derivitie I end up with $-n*-1/(1-\theta)$ how should I proceed? Because I cannot set this equal to zero and get a value for $\theta$

I know this has some relations possibly with order statistics but I am not sure how to derive MLE for it.

Comment: Hello @Mona, are you sure of the PDF $f(x \vert \theta)$ that you've shared ? It's not a PDF

Comment: that's a good question tbh! Instructor mentioned if there is a typo tell it and get bonus points! Last semester I had a similar one 1/theta and for that I used order statistics. I am not sure how order statistics would make sense here exactly. can you tell why it is wrong?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi also why does it need to be a PDF to begin with? thanks for explanation

Comment: Maximum likelihood is the maximum of the likelihood function, which is a pdf..

Comment: oh the lower bound of $x$ is $\theta$.. so it is now a PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cannot set derivative to zero, it means the maximum occurs at the boundary.  Indeed, it is clear the maximum occurs at $\theta=\min x_i$ if you actually kept the indicator in your likelihood function:
$$P(x\mid\theta)=(1-\theta)^{-1}1_{\theta\leq x\leq 1}$$
So with independent $x_1,\dots,x_n$, we get
$$L(\theta)=L(\theta\mid x_1,\dots,x_n)=(1-\theta)^{-n}1_{\theta\leq\min x_i}1_{\max x_i\leq 1}$$
and hence the derivative
$$
(\log L)'(\theta\mid x_1,\dots,x_n)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{n}{1-\theta}>0 & \theta<\min x_i\leq\max x_i\leq 1\\
0 & \theta>\min x_i\text{ or }\max x_i>1
\end{cases}
$$
Hence the maximum occurs at $\theta=\min x_i$ by left-continuity of our $L(\theta)$

Comment: can you explain a little further how you derive that? Actually, it is not clear or obvious for me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is more clear now. The last equation you wrote is related to "Ordered Statistics"?

Comment: also, would it be no different than 1/(-theta) like the 1 in the denominator has no effect?

Comment: also I think there is a typo in your second line inequalities

Comment: In a sense yes but really no.  It is merely a relic of $(\min x_i, \max x_i)$ being a sufficient statistic for uniform distribution with unknown lower and upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

So lets write down the PDF of $n$ independent samples generated from $x \vert \theta$, i.e
\begin{equation}
 f(x_1 \ldots x_n \vert \theta)
 =
 f(x_1 \vert \theta)
 \ldots
 f(x_n \vert \theta)
 =
 \frac{1}{(1 - \theta)^n},
\qquad 
\theta < x_k < 1, \quad
 k = 1 \ldots n
\end{equation}
The log likelihood is the log of the above function, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 l(\theta) = \log \frac{1}{(1 - \theta)^n}
 =
 - n \log (1 - \theta)
\end{equation}
Maximizing the $l(\theta)$ is equivalent to minimizing $-l(\theta)$ 
\begin{equation}
 \hat{\theta} 
 =
 \operatorname{argmin}_{\theta}
 \log (1 - \theta)
\end{equation}
Now, if you do the derivative, as you say, you will not get anywhere. However, the minimum is clear, it is at $\theta = 1$, you'd get $-\infty$ as the optimum value. BUT, you have constraints here, which is that 
\begin{equation}
 \theta < x_k < 1 \qquad
 k = 1 \ldots n
\end{equation}
So to minimize $\log (1 - \theta)$ subject to the $n$ constraints, you must estimate $\theta$ as 
\begin{equation}
 \hat{\theta} = \min \lbrace x_i \rbrace_{i=1}^n
\end{equation}

**PS: A more rigorous mathematical arguement is by deriving the Lagrangian function taking into account the above inequalities, but here the problem is easy to solve. You need $\theta$ as close as possible to $1$ without violating the constraints. The only way to do so is by picking the minimum of the sample values.**